# Using Ansible ini_file with nested dict?

Tags: ansible, configuration-management

What I am trying to achieve is the following. Suppose we have a playbook *similar* to the following one:

```
---

- hosts: local
  tasks:
    - ini_file:
      path: test.ini
      create: yes
      section: "{{???}}"
      option: "{{???}}"
      value: "{{???}}"
    loop: "{{inidict ...???}}"
  vars:
    inidict:
      section1:
        option1: value1
        option2: value2
      section2:
        option1: value1
        option2: value2
```

The above playbook is invalid because of the lines with `???` in them.

Now my goal here is to map this dict to sections/options/values inside the INI file and get the following INI contents:

```
[section1]
option1 = value1
option2 = value2

[section2]
option1 = value1
option2 = value2
```

Unfortunately this appears to be failing as I need to add a secondary level of nesting for the loop to *somehow* loop over sections in the outer loop and then over options/values in the inner one.

Is there a more elegant or "ansibly" (for lack of an Ansible term corresponding to pythonic) way to achieve this than by wrapping one loop level in a role and iterating over section names using, say `include_role`, while passing the section name and list of options/values as a variable?

I suppose one alternative could be to "flatten" the dictionary in a way that would yield something that amounts to (YAML):

```
  vars:
    inicontents:
      - section: section1
        key: option1
        value: value1
      - section: section1
        key: option2
        value: value2
      - section: section2
        key: option1
        value: value1
      - section: section2
        key: option2
        value: value2
```

I'd just like to keep it DRY and avoid the duplication of the section name, when clearly the dict would perfectly map onto the "data model" of the INI file.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a way to do this with ansible by default other than using your "flattened" version. Fortunately you can have the best of both worlds and write your own filter plugin for flattening the dict for you. Just add something like the following to the `filter_plugins` directory in your project directory or in `~/.ansible/plugins/filter_plugins` and name it something like `filters.py`:

```
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return { 'ini_dict_flatten': self.ini_dict_flatten }

    def ini_dict_flatten(self, arg):
        ret = []
        for section, subdict in arg.items():
            for key, value in subdict.items():
                ret.append(dict(section=section,
                                key=key,
                                value=value))
        return ret
```

After this you can use the new filter in your project like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - ini_file:
        path: /tmp/test.ini
        create: yes
        section: "{{ item.section }}"
        option: "{{ item.key }}"
        value: "{{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ inidict | ini_dict_flatten }}"
  vars:
    inidict:
      section1:
        option1: value1
        option2: value2
      section2:
        option1: value1
        option2: value2
```

It helps sometimes if you know python since that way you can write your own plugins for ansible.

EDIT: I will include a much less readable and not recommended solution as well. Since the `loop:` works with json formatted strings and jinja2 is applied to strings in ansible before they're processed you can use jinja logic to create the "flattened" layout for you directly in the playbook. This solution is a lot uglier and less reusable than writing your own filter but technically still works.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    inidict:
      section1:
        option1: value1
        option2: value2
      section2:
        option1: value1
        option2: value2
  tasks:
    - ini_file:
        path: /tmp/test.ini
        create: yes
        section: "{{ item.section }}"
        option: "{{ item.key }}"
        value: "{{ item.value }}"
      loop: >-
        [
        {% for section, subdict in inidict.items() %}
          {% for key, value in subdict.items() %}
            {'section': '{{ section }}',
             'key': '{{ key }}',
             'value': '{{ value }}'}
            {% if not loop.last %}
              ,
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% if not loop.last %}
            ,
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        ]
```